# Tick placement for radial plot with log-scale for r

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale

I'm trying to create a radial plot with a logrithmic scale on the r-axis, but the tick labels for the theta are coming up inside the plot.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(1)
r = 10**(1 + 2*np.random.rand(36))
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, 37)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.plot(theta, r)
# We need to reset the minimum r-limit to avoid log(0)
ax.set_rlim(0.1, None)
ax.set_rscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image: Radial plot with log-scale for r]

The theta ticks are inside the figure, which doesn't look so bad here, but are hidden for e.g. a pcolormesh plot - for comparison, if I comment out the `set_rlim` and `set_rscale` lines, we get the following with the desired location for the ticks. (For anyone using dark mode, the image background is transparent so the ticks might not show inline.)

[image: Radial plot with linear scale for r]

I've tried looking at the `ax.get_xticklabels` but the y-position (equivalently the r-position) is 0.

```
[Text(0.0, 0, '0°'),
 Text(0.7853981633974483, 0, '45°'),
 Text(1.5707963267948966, 0, '90°'),
 Text(2.356194490192345, 0, '135°'),
 Text(3.141592653589793, 0, '180°'),
 Text(3.9269908169872414, 0, '225°'),
 Text(4.71238898038469, 0, '270°'),
 Text(5.497787143782138, 0, '315°')]
```

Interestingly, if you increate the upper `rlim` (e.g. `ax.set_rlim([0.1, 1e5])`) the ticks move right to the edge of the figure.

Comment: Perhaps related to this issue: [pcolormesh in log polar coordinates #12803](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12803)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`Axes.tick_params()`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) to set the `pad` distance between the ticks and labels:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rmin(0.1)
ax.set_rscale('log')

ax.tick_params(pad=35)
```

[image: polar plot with tick params padding]

Comment: Cheers for this.  If the data instead goes higher, e.g. for data `r = 10**(7 + 2*np.random.rand(36))` the 35 padding would need to be reduced.  Any thoughts on not setting this manually for each plot?

Comment: @Steve Sorry I don't know how to do it automatically. I tried seaborn since sometimes it fixes matplotlib's formatting quirks, but `set_rscale('log')` also messed up the tick labels with seaborn as well.